# Snowflake SQL using set

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
set test=code;
set test2=code2;

alter account set comp='{
"test"= "abc",
"test2"="abc2"
}';
```

Here I am trying to refer set test=code, test2=code2 in the below alter account block instead of providing values directly in that block. After trying test=$test. It is not working. Is there any way to refer above test test2 in the alter account block. Thanks

Comment: What is this parameter? "comp"

Comment: Hi, it's identify provider. I changed it to random name

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish here. What's the schema of the table and desired end result?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Variables can be referenced by using $name.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html

Comment: When I do that it is just taking it as a string. Same for identifier. I think i should use something like concat but I am missing in logic or some env variable. Thanks